# Move an entire folder from a server to another using SSH

Tags: ssh

I'm changing the look of my site and to avoid working on the live site, I used a new hetzner server on which I tried to make all the changes with a version of the site updated 15 days ago. With the occasion, I also chose a better server to have better performance once finished. Now to align the two sites, the live site and the one where I made the changes, I imported the last articles added on the live site but I can't import the images.

So I would like to copy the whole images folder from the live server to the dummy one. I only have the SSH access data. Can you help me?

I use Windows 10 and Putty, but eventually, I also have a Mac with terminal

Comment: Connect to the server with a tool like WinSCP (set your credentals as "SFTP") and transfer your data there. To speed up the process and avoid transferring many small files, you could try first creating a `.tar.gz` archive, transfer that, and later unpack it on the other server (you can do that either via SSH or by right-clicking in WinSCP and looking under "custom commands").

Answer (score 0):

You can do it this way:

```
scp -rp sourcedirectory user@dest:/path
```

- -r means recursive
- -p preserves modification times, access times, and modes from the original file.

Note: This creates the sourcedirectory inside /path thus the files will be in /path/sourcedirectory